# Fastlane codesign on Travis CI hangs - popup assumed

Tags: travis-ci, fastlane

I'm using Fastlane and Travis CI. When my fastfile runs: 'gym' hangs on Travis CI, but on my local it runs fine. I do remember pressing a button to allow a certificate to be used on my local machine.

I think that's what must be happening on Travis CI as when I show all debug, the last line is a codesign and it just hangs. Is there anyway to force Fastlane/Travis CI to accept the certificate?

Maybe something like:

```
gym (clean: true, accept_ui_certificate: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Until we have a better solution, you can add the following to your `Fastfile`: https://github.com/wwdc-family/app/blob/master/ios/fastlane/Fastfile#L5-L19

```
if is_ci
  password = SecureRandom.base64
  keychain_name = "fastlane"
  ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME"] = keychain_name
  ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"] = password

  create_keychain(
    name: keychain_name,
    default_keychain: true,
    unlock: true,
    timeout: 3600,
    lock_when_sleeps: true,
    password: password
  )
end
```